# Using React with a wordpress theme, how do I set it up?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I have setup a react theme for `Wordpress` using `WP REST API`.

How do I get my files working in the wordpress theme folder?

I have my `dist` folder, which has my `bundle.js` and styles. How do I get these files working on the wordpress backend so my site is functional?

Thanks

Comment: I hope this helps at least a little: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66983776/258462.