# How to compile the JS file to use a React component in a WordPress theme if I do not need SSR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, webpack, create-react-app

I have a WordPress theme and for a part of it I want to use a React component (I don't need SSR). I have used create-react-app in the past but now I have this code:

```html
<div id="react-nav-bar"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/react-nav-bar/build/static/js/runtime-main.39639aca.js"></script>
```

and it does not work. The request to `runtime-main.39639aca.js` succeeds but it does not load my nav bar.

The issue is that create-react-app produces more than a JS file, and I need just a JS file that I can put in the theme.

I have tried some things with webpack without success. I searched on GitHub and there are some things, I do not know which one to try. I tried [react-embedded](https://github.com/the-duck/react-embedded) and it threw me an error. I also tried [this](https://medium.com/@CodeCareerCoach/react-app-inside-a-wordpress-page-or-post-4c7d38181b3d) but it does not work for me.

I also dislike the ES Lint warnings (I use VS Code).

## Update 1

This command does what I want, partially:

```sh
npx babel --watch react-nav-bar/src --out-dir react-nav-bar/dist --presets react-app/prod
```

This is how I've tried without WebPack, but the editor in VS Code is filled with red squiggles although it compiles well, and I cannot import npm modules. Is there a way to be able to import npm modules? Autocompletion makes me *a lot* more productive.

Comment: Do you even need webpack? If you're only using a component without any styles (or if you're using external styles), then compiling it with babel or typescript will do the trick. JSX is basically just Javascript (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwMIgLYAdwFMywLwwAUAlDHgHwwDeAUDPTAE5ZQCujYMAPACYCWAN3IoM2XFwD0-ITQC+QA)

Comment: @Felix I've tried without WebPack but the editor in VS Code is filled with red squiggles although it compiles well, and I cannot import npm modules. Is there a way to be able to import npm modules? Autocompletion makes me a lot more productive.

Comment: not without any bundler (webpack, rollup, ...). typescript and babel only transpile your TSX/JSX. Everything else is up to you or a bundler. Even if you use webpack, there's a babel or typescript compiler, which transpiles your code. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/ Try the typescript link above to see what those compilers really do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) a try and it works beautifully.

I get some warnings in the DevTools console but it works! With autocompletion and npm module includes.

Based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bcherny/eb11719f9fbe6b01412da7c64feb44c3) I have these files:

## src/index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  return <button onClick={() => alert('React from WordPress !')}>Cool!!!</button>;
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-nav-bar'));
});
```

## package.json

Just two additional scripts:

```
"build": "rollup -c",
"watch": "rollup -cw"
```

The unusual dependencies when compared with the gist linked above:

```
"@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^18.0.0",
"@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.2.1",
"rollup-plugin-typescript": "^1.0.1",
```

## rollup.config.js

```js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
    input: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        file: './dist/bundle.js',
    },
    format: 'iife',
    plugins: [ resolve(), typescript(), commonjs() ],
};
```

## tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

For React to work with this I have the special line: `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`.

## ../footer.php

```html
<div id="react-nav-bar"></div>

<script>try { process.env.NODE_ENV } catch(e) { var process = { env: { NODE_ENV: 'production' } }; }</script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/react-nav-bar/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

This helped a lot: https://github.com/hybridsjs/hybrids/issues/27#issuecomment-452346986